# Faraday Authorization Header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, faraday

I am trying to make a request to the `Spingo` API. I have made a successful request using Curl, but am trying to use the Faraday gem.

The successful curl request looks like this:

```
curl -v --url "calendarapi.spingo.com/v1/events?sections=42336"  --header 'Authorization: SpingoAPI token="my-api-key"'
```

Inititially I tried tried using the default adapter `net-http`. Then I switched to the `Typheous` adapter because `net-http` was capitalizing my `SpingoAPI` scheme in the Authorization header. This made it read Spingoapi. Now my request looks like this:

```
  def make_request
      conn = Faraday.new(base_url) do |f|
          f.params['sections'] = '42336'
          f.adapter :typhoeus
          f.use Faraday::Response::Logger
      end
      conn.authorization(:SpingoAPI, token: api_key)
      conn.get
  end
```

Switching to `Typheous` allowed something to return (I wasn't getting anything back from `net-http`) So my response looks like this.

```
ETHON: performed EASY effective_url=url
sections=42336 response_code=200 return_code=ok total_time=0.844381
I, [2015-08-05T11:16:06.575611 #22692]  INFO -- : get http://www.calendarapi.spingo.com/v1/events?sections=42336
D, [2015-08-05T11:16:06.575842 #22692] DEBUG -- request: User-Agent: "Faraday v0.9.1"

Authorization: "SpingoAPI token=\"my-token\""
I, [2015-08-05T11:16:06.576081 #22692]  INFO -- Status: 200
D, [2015-08-05T11:16:06.576230 #22692] DEBUG -- response: Content-Type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
Date: "Wed, 05 Aug 2015 17:16:03 GMT"
Server: "nginx/1.2.9"
Set-Cookie: "VisitorID=GsPJ8NLBiP; expires=Tue, 03-Nov-2015 17:16:03 GMT"
X-Powered-By: "PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11"
Content-Length: "152"
Connection: "keep-alive"
```

This leads me to believe that I am not being authorized, however I am out of ideas on how to pass in the authorization differently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well silly answer, but the thing that made it work was removing the www off of the base url I had in place. Apparently the domain wasn't set up to accept it with or without.

Answer (score 15):

try this :

```
# set variables
base_url = "calendarapi.spingo.com"
url = "/v1/events"
token = "SpingoAPI token='my-api-key'"
params = {:sections => 42336}


# init connection object
connection = Faraday.new(:url => base_url) do |c|
   c.use Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded
   c.use Faraday::Response::Logger
   c.use Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp
end

# send request
response = connection.get url, params do |request|
  request.headers["Authorization"] = token
end
```